# Retrieve Primaryclass column in cassandra - Could not find field for property during fallback access

Tags: java, cassandra

How to access the fields inside the `primarykeyclass` with `@query` annotation?

Entity

```java
@Table(value = "table1")
@Data
public class DTable implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public CassandraPrimaryKeyclass key;

    @Column("CREATED_TMSTAMP")
    private String createdTimeStamp;
}
```

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class CassandraPrimaryKeyclass implements Serializable  {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "KEY_NAME", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    public String serviceKeyName;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "KEY_VALUE", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    public String serviceKeyValue;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name ="EMP_ID",ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    public String empID;    
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query("select key.EMP_ID from table1 WHERE KEY_NAME=?0 AND KEY_VALUE=?1 )
    public Mono<KeyValuePair> ParllelMultireadkeyValue(String serviceKeyName, String serviceKeyValue);
```

This throws

> Could not find field for property during fallback access!

How to access the column in the Primary key class?

Comment: Hi @Aparna, could you please update your original post/question with the version of the Cassandra that you're running along with the driver maven coordinates to help readers triage this better? TY!

Comment: @Madhavan : Cassandra version : V.6.8.0

Comment: Thank you. I understand you're leveraging [DataStax Enterprise (DSE) version `6.8.0`](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) here. How about the programming language, and driver versions? Unreleated, but just to let you know that `6.8.0` is super old version and the latest version as of this writing is `6.8.29`. See [the DSE `6.8` release notes here](https://github.com/datastax/release-notes/blob/master/DSE_6.8_Release_Notes.md#release-notes-for-datastax-enterprise-68) & [patch release documentation](https://docs.datastax.com) for additional details.